# Kotlin Flow and Websockets with clean architecture on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Recently, our team tried to implement websockets. We easily thought to use Rx when listening on events but I wondered how to do without it. So, we tried the famous Kotlin `Flow` but I don't know if our implementation is correct.

Our app's architecture is splitted in four layers:

- Service - emits and receives events from socket,
- Repository - filters, maps, transforms, etc,
- ViewModel - populates the LiveDatas
- Activity - observes the changes and updates UI.

Therefore, we listen the events received into the Service as follows:

```
fun listenMessages(): Flow<List<Message>> = channelFlow {
    socket.on("NewMessage") { args ->
        val message = gson.fromJson(args[0].toString(), ...)
        trySend(message)
    }
    awaitClose()
}
```

We use `channelFlow`'s coroutine to send to the consumer when an event is received with `trySend` and we keep this `Flow` alive by using `awaitClose`.

The Repository does some logic after catching the `Flow` and sends it back to the ViewModel:

```
fun getMessages(): Flow<List<Message>> {
    return service.listenMessages()
            .filter { ... }
            .map { ... }
}
```

Then, the ViewModel launches the coroutines and updates the LiveData when collecting the `Flow`:

```
fun getMessages() {
    viewModelScope.launch(context = Dispatcher.IO) {
        repository.getMessages()
                .collect {
                    messagesLiveData.postValue(it)
                }
    }
}
```

This works well however this raises some questions:

- Is this the correct implementation?
- When we need to constantly listening, does `channelFlow` is the right choice?
- In this case, should we use classic `Channel`s instead of `Flow` (*hot* vs *cold*)?

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of channels is meant as a primitive to mainly communicate between coroutines [1](https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c). As far as I understand it based on the `channelFlow` [docs](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html), it uses a `Channel` under the hood and translates it to a `Flow`. By using a `Channel` under the hood, there is something important to realize:

> every value that is sent to the channel is received once. You cannot use channels to distribute events or state updates in a way that allows multiple subscribers to independently receive and react upon them. [1](https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c)

Depending on your architecture this may not matter, but this example may illustrate something important:

```
fun ws(): Flow<List<Message>> = channelFlow {
    println("channelFlow block called")
    trySend(listOf(Message(0), Message(1)))
    delay(2_000)
    trySend(listOf(Message(2)))
}

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val source = ws()

    launch {
        source.collect {
            println("First collect got $it")
        }
    }
    launch {
        source.collect {
            println("Second collect got $it")
        }
    }
}
```

Which generates the output:

```
channelFlow block called
channelFlow block called
First collect got [Message(id=0), Message(id=1)]
Second collect got [Message(id=0), Message(id=1)]
First collect got [Message(id=2)]
Second collect got [Message(id=2)]
```

Since a `Channel` cannot be shared, each time `.collect` is called on `source`, it triggers the `channelFlow` body to be called! What may be more suprising is that the same `Flow` is referenced via `source`, there is not a new call to `ws()` going on.

Looking more closely at the `channelFlow` docs you can see that

> The resulting flow is cold, which means that block is called every time a terminal operator is applied to the resulting flow.[2](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html)

Since `.collect()` is a terminal operator, it triggers a new call to the `channelFlow` body.

Now, does this matter for your use case? I'm not sure; you will have to figure out if you are subscribing to the flow produced by `listenMessages` in multiple locations, or if the body of that `channelFlow` is expensive to perform more than once.

As a more general recommendation, I would suggest to be more explicit about the behavior of your service. Should `listenMessages` emit to everyone that is subscribed? Should it only emit to the first one that is available (see also [fan-out behavior](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html))? If you prefer the former, a [`SharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) would be recommended, if the later I would be explicit about exposing a `Channel` directly so you don't confuse downstream consumers about the issue I showed above.

Comment: Reading all articles from [Roman Elizarov](https://elizarov.medium.com) was really helpful. I refactored our code to use for example `callbackFlow` instead of `channelFlow` and made other improvements. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I appreciated.